# c void main function? returning 16 value

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am writing a c program with void main function in code blocks.

I just write return with no value.
The program is as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
void main (void)   
{  
  printf ("ali tariq\n");  
  return;  
}
```

However, in the console window the program returns the value 16 in the console window.  "Process returned 16"

I want to know why it is returning this value?
How can i utilize this value in windows using codeblocks?

Thanks

Comment: Let me ask you this: since a C program is supposed to return an exit status, since environments such as the console window tend to report the status (particularly if nonzero), and since your program goes out of its way to *not* return the necessary exit status, what did you *expect* would happen?

Answer (score 5):

In (hosted) C the `main` function must return an `int` (C11§5.1.2.2.1[1]). By declaring it with a return type of `void`, and not specifying any return value you invoke *undefined behaviour*. This means the compiler is free to return anything and in your case it turns out to be 16.

Comment: All good answers. I find this one to be the clearest of all 3. For simpletons like me.

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** free to declare the return type of `main` as you wish. Why?

1. BECAUSE YOU DIDN'T WRITE THE CODE CALLING main(). Sorry 'bout the shouting, but someone else wrote that code and placed it in `crt0.o` or so. Your main() is linked against that code and it can't just return what it wants because that code expects an `int`. Always. It's already written and compiled. You understand this subtle point?
2. Because the C Standard says so. See other answer by Kninnug for Chapter and Verse.

In other words, your code invokes *undefined behavior* and it should be no surprise to find a garbage value where no value was provided.

So you expected a warning from the compiler? The better ones indeed will catch this with the right options. E.g. gcc and clang support `-Wmain-return-type`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `void main()`, use `int main()` instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14349783)

Comment: @EliSadoff This provided an answer, he must use `int main()` instead of `void main()`

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior. First of all according to the C Standard main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

You declared the function as having return type `void`. In this case the process that starts the program can not get a valid return code of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a function is declared as void doesn't mean it won't return anything. On the x86, for example, a lot of  calling conventions specify that the value in the register `EAX` after a function call is the return value of the function.  So, if you have a C function that is declared  `void` but the machine code for the function changes the value of `EAX`, that will get treated as the return value for the function.

Answer (score 0):

**EVERY** "normal" program that terminate execution **WITHOUT** errors, must return **ZERO**.

So, your program must be:

```
#include<stdio.h>   

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) // your program may have command line parameters
{  
    printf ("ali tariq\n");  
    return 0; // Program terminate with NO ERRORS
}
```

However there are cases when one program may terminate **WITH** errors.

Let's suppose this:

```
#include<stdio.h>    

void main (int argc, char *argv[])   
{  
    // program to make a division between two numbers

    double a, b, res;

    a = b = res = 0.0;

    printf ("Enter 1st number: ");
    scanf ("%lf", &a);
    printf ("Enter 2nd number: ");
    scanf ("%lf", &b);

    if (b == 0) return 1; // division by '0' then return ERROR (any number != 0)

    printf ("%f / %f = %f", a, b, a/b);

    return 0; // NO ERROR
}
```

Now you may ask: «But where is the return value evaluated?

Answer: «By the Operating System.»

One batch file may run your program and read the integer YOU returned in the environment variable 'ERRORLEVEL'